# Xcode @autoreleasepool error on project Run

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have an app that i'm building with phonegap (html5/js) and this @autoreleasepool error has appeared from nowhere all of a sudden and I'm not an xcode developer so unsure of how to fix this.

The code that gets highlighted is:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

I've tried turning Automatic Reference Counting to No as per suggestions from other threads, however, this isn't working.

Any ideas what could be causing this? Thanks in advance!

Screenshot:
http://cl.ly/image/2x2g33371D3w

Comment: what is the actual error?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be one, the code just breaks and points at the above code.

Comment: do you have exception breakpoints turned on? If not, you can try to add one by going to View > Navigators > Show Breakpoint Navigator, hit the + button in the bottom left, and select "Add Exception Breakpoint"

Comment: That didn't seem to really help me out... i've updated the original thread with a screenshot of the xcode window - hope this helps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an error. You have accidentally set a breakpoint on line 13 in the main.m. Since this line is the comment, the actual breakpoint moves down to the `@autorelease` statement.

Just remove the breakpoint (grab the blue arrow and drag it to the right) and everything should be fine.