# Xcode Cordova crashes after add Firebase plugin

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, firebase, hybrid

I'm developing IOS app on Xcode with Cordova 7.1.0.

After i build cordova-plugin-firebase (0.1.24), the application started to crash.

main.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

I tried

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7012504/5967421

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22743261/5967421

https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-hot-code-push-local-dev-addon/issues/12

https://kakshilshahblog.wordpress.com/2016/10/02/finding-error-line-number-thread-1-sigabrt-error-exc_crash/

**Error messages**
Thread 1 signal SIGABRT

Actually Xcode says 'Build succesful'. After splash screen disappear in emulator, app stopping.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMlb7.png)

Comment: Thank you for replying. Message is 'Thread 1 signal SIGABRT'

Comment: I am facing the same issue, were you able to solve this?